# I have deleted all files from Nuxt project and created new index.vue file but still showing old content on browser

Tags: nuxt.js

I have deleted all files from Nuxt project and created new index.vue file but still showing old content on browser

I want to create new page

Comment: Have you tried hard reloading? `Ctrl + Shift + R` and `Emptying Cache and Hard Reload`?

Comment: Probably in the wrong project (check that you're editing what you're expecting).

Comment: yes I have tried hard reloading even I restarted the system but nothing works

Comment: I am in the same project